# Flexible, compatible alternative to FILE / fopen I/O

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream, fopen

I have a bunch of legacy code that uses C-style file I/O (using `FILE*` streams, `fprintf`, `fscanf`, etc.) that I'd like to update to operate off of other data sources (e.g., downloading from or posting to the web, or to or from a custom data transfer cable).

If it used iostreams, this would be an easy update, but it doesn't.

Are there any C or C++ libraries for I/O that support different kinds of streams but that are source-compatible or mostly source-compatible with C's `FILE*` stream functions?

If source compatibility is too much to ask, I'd settle for "able to be search-and-replaced with a Perl script."  `fprintf` and `fscanf` seem to be the major obstacles here; I haven't found any `iostream`-compatible versions of these.

I'm looking for a solution that will work in both Windows and Linux.

**Example**

As a trivial example, I have code like the following:

```
FILE *input = fopen(filename, "rt");
fscanf(input, "%d,%d,%d,%f", &f_id, &f_units, &h_index, &h_default);
fclose(input);
```

I'd like to update it to handle data that's of the same format but may come from other sources, without having to worry about the intricacies of how exactly to replicate `fscanf`'s semantics myself (since I have many, many `fscanf` and `fprintf` calls that would need updating).  Something like this would work, except that I've been unable to find anything like `istream_scanf`:

```
std::istream *input = make_http_istream(url);
istream_scanf(*input, &f_id, &f_units, &h_index, &h_default);
delete input;
```

Comment: Can you give a trivial example of what you're looking for?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by iostream-compatible versions of fprintf?

Comment: @Robᵩ - Windows and Linux.  I've updated my question; thanks.